# Can you help find me with finding relationship between these numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image: We are doing a research and result was this. It seems so pretty but I can't find why]

As I wrote on the description, I tried only to fail... Can you find the relationship between these numbers?

Comment: Looks like a parabola. Try finding $a,b,c$ such that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ using the least squares approximation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#:~:text=The%20method%20of%20least%20squares,results%20of%20every%20single%20equation.

Comment: Mathematica (or you could try Wolfram Alpha) gave me this: $$52.4771 - 1.65105 x + 0.270378 x^2.$$ I used `Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]` where `data={{1, 50}, {2,50}, ...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the differences $\Delta_1$ (playing the role of a derivative) , then the differences of the differences : $\Delta_2$  (playing the role of a second derivative). You are advised to consider a fitting by a second degree relationship ; but this case happens iff $\Delta_2$ is approximately constant (this is based on the finite-differences calculus with strong analogy with the usual calculus ; see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Finite-difference_calculus)).

As

$$\Delta_2=    0.3, \ 0.3, \ 0.2, \ 0.5, \ 0.4, \ 0.4, \ 0.4, \ 0.6, \  0.6, \ 0.8, \  0.8, \ 1.1, \ 1.5$$

is only approximately constant in the mid-range but is strongly divergent on the right side, we cannot consider a quadratic fit as **globally satisfying**. It would be better at least for the tail of your distribution to consider an exponential fit.